# Lua overloads the operator to create a fake array

Tags: lua, lua-table

I want to create a 0-memory lua array that actually jumps to my custom function when I use operators like `#` `[]` on it

Any ideas on how to do this?

I want the user using this fake array to not perceive it as fake, it is worse than a normal array in terms of access speed, but has better memory performance

Comment: Just implement `__len`, `__pairs` and `__index` metamethods for your fake array.

Answer (score 2):

Lua implements something called metamethods ([documentation](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.4))

Metamethods are functions which exist subsequently to a table and fire on certain operations such as indexing the array, reading missing indices, gathering the length of the array, or even math operations such as `+ - * /`

```
-- Start by creating your array, and another for demonstration purposes
local object = {}
local demo = {1, 2, 3, 4}

-- Create a your metamethods contained in a table
local metamethods = {
    __index = function(self, index) return demo[index] end;
    __newindex = function(self, index, value) demo[index] = value end;
}

-- Lets print out what is in the object table for demonstration
print(object[1]) -- nil
print(object[2]) -- nil
print(object[3]) -- nil
print(object[4]) -- nil

-- Use the setmetatable(table a, table b) function to set the metamethods
-- stored in 'b' to 'a'
setmetatable(object, metamethods);

-- Lets print out what is in the object table for demonstration
print(object[1]) -- 1
print(object[2]) -- 2
print(object[3]) -- 3
print(object[4]) -- 4
```

Why does the above code work? When a metatable is set with the index `__index` (`metamethods.__index`), if the attached table's (`object`) is indexed and the key isn't present (`nil`), then it will call the specified function. In the __index function, it returns the demo's table with the index passed straight to it. So its as if: when you do `object[1]`, you actually do `demo[1]` but with a metamethod's help of course. This effectively creates a proxy of sorts.

One cool and quick usage of setmetatable() is that it returns the value you pass as the first parameter (a table).

```
local object1 = setmetatable({}, { __index = function(self, i) return 1 end })

print(object1["a"]) -- 1
print(object2[321]) -- 1
```